# Visual Studio multiline replace while ignoring leading spaces on find, but including them on replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio extension [Multiline Search and Replace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterMacej.MultilineSearchandReplace), trying to make a multiline replace.

**General purpose:**

I'd like to be able *ignore* leading spaces on *find*, but *include* leading spaces on *replace*.

**Example**

Say we have the following code:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class TestCase
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int? num1 = 2;
            int? num2 = null;
            bool isLarger = num1 > num2;
        }
    }
}
```

... and let's say we'd like to replace the code:

```
int? num2 = null;
bool isLarger
```

... with:

```
int? num2 = null;
var larger
```

So we'd get:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class TestCase
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int? num1 = 2;
            int? num2 = null;
            var larger = num1 > num2;
        }
    }
}
```

**Regex for finding**

In the example above, the regex for finding the text (generated by the VS extension) is:

```
num2 = null;((\r\n)|\n|\r)( |\t)*var larger()
```

**What's the regex for replacing?**

Comment: is issue resolved?

Comment: @fenixil I resolved it posting a working solution, see my answer below. Your solution does not work in Visual Studio since its regex engine is a bit "tweaked" and does not behaves as most other non-editor-tool-oriented regex implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get the job done with the default search and replace dialog:

**Find What**:      `\b(num2 = null;\r\s*)bool isLarger\b`
Or
**Find What**:      `\b(num2 = null;[\r\s]*)bool isLarger\b`
**Replace With**: `$1var larger`

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(num2 = null;\r\s*)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1` retrieves this value):

  - `num2 = null;` - a literal string
  - `\r` - line break sequence
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces (this pattern does not match line breaks if used without `\r` in VS)
- `bool isLarger` - a string
- `\b` - word boundary.

Test:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Downvoter: the solution is correct and working. See proof above. Please check before downvoting, as false downvotes mislead OP and future visitors.

Comment: Seems someone enjoyed downvoting the valid question and the valid answer. Accepted and upvoted.
BTW, for future reference, just as another example: `\b(\);\r\s*)\b` will capture a `)` character followed by a `;` character.